# Why the covariance is zero for independent variables?

Tags: covariance, independence

when the two independent variables are uncorrelated the covariance seems to be zero. Is there any equation for it which describes the fact?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_correlation

Comment: i couldn't found any solving equations about zero covariance.Can you please help?

Comment: Just expand the product in the definition of covariance and use independence to see that covariance is 0

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer with the details

Answer (score 7):

If you know that $\rho_{X Y} = \sigma_{X Y} / (\sigma_X \sigma_Y)$ is zero, then $\sigma_{X Y}$ must be zero.

Note that the covariance of two independent variables is $\sigma_{X Y} = E[(X-EX)(Y-EY)] = E[X Y] - E[X] E[Y] = 0$, because by independence $E[X Y] = E[X] E[Y]$.

Answer (score 0):

yes, definitely if the two random variable is independent then the covariance is zero.
suppose **X** and **Y** be two independent random variable then occurrence of **X** or **Y** does affect the occurrence of **Y**

i.e

**P(X/Y) = P(X)** and **P(Y/X) = P(Y)**

i.e

**P(XY) = P(X)P(Y)**

also we know that

**COV(XY) = E[X-E(X)] [Y-E(Y)]**

```
    = E[XY] - E[X] E[Y]
    = ΣXYP(XY) - ΣXP(X) ΣYP(Y)
    = ΣXYP(X)P(Y) - ΣXYP(X)P(Y)
    = 0
```

Here **ΣXY = ΣX ΣY**

> (as these are the finite convergent series.)